# datepicker send data to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How i can get picked data in inline mode. 
With popup its easy to do with input tag
`<input type="hidden" id="defaultInlineDatepicker" size="60">`. And when i can write data to database. But i need calendar on my page inline.

```
     <p>
     <span id="defaultInlineDatepicke" class="datepicker"></span>&nbsp;

     </p>


<script>     
$('#defaultInlineDatepicke').datepick({multiSelect: 999,
 showOn: 'both', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'img/calendar.gif'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker is not an input tag, it is a UI enhancement plugin. SO you need to change the span to an input field.

```
<p> 
     <input id="defaultInlineDatepicke" class="datepicker" type="text"/> 
</p> 



<script>      
    $('#defaultInlineDatepicke').datepick({multiSelect: 999, 
      showOn: 'both', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'img/calendar.gif'}); 
</script>
```

Comment: yeah i know, but then i must click on the field to get popup calendar. I need to see calendar all the time inline..

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for you:

**Script:**:

```
$(function() {
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    altField: '#datepicker_pick',
    onSelect: function() {
         alert($("#datepicker_pick").val());
    }
 });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="datepicker_pick" name="datepicker_pick">
```